# Angularjs date time day picker

Tags: angularjs, datetimepicker

I would like to know if there is an angularjs datepicker or other that can do the following:

1. Pick date and time.
2. Pick day and time.
3. Pick only time.

Thanks

Comment: https://danielykpan.github.io/date-time-picker/ ? which version of angular?

Comment: @G_S angular v1.3.15

Answer (score 0):

you can use moment picker, check:
https://github.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker

Comment: Does it have an option to pick only day and time and only time?

Comment: set  format as you want. Check the link  given: https://plnkr.co/edit/9aEYXbY1AowQxWS35QAb?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Found below options from npm

- [angular-jquery-timepicker](http://recras.github.io/angular-jquery-timepicker/)
- [angular-ui-bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ui-bootstrap-datetimepicker)
- [bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker](https://github.com/Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker)

All the above contains separate date picker and time picker.
Take a look at them.

Answer (score 0):

There is also my directive, which meets all of your requirements - See https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker